# Get and use url hash for server side display purposes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, hash

I am trying to get the hash value out of a url from client side and then use that value to determine how a menu should be displayed.  This means I need to do 2 things:

1. Get the hash value
2. Set my timing right so I can access the value of the hash early enough to make my menu change.

For 1, I am trying to use jQuery to get the hash and store it in hidden input from an example I saw on this site.  I am able to confirm through Firebug that this is working correctly.

```
<input id="urlhash" type="hidden" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            var hiddenUrlHash = document.getElementById("<%:urlhash.ClientID%>");
            hiddenUrlHash.value = window.location.hash;
        });   
</script>
```

Part 2 is where I am stuck.  As a test, I have some code in the code behind to simply display the hidden input value in a text box.  However, nothing is appearing in the textbox.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxTest.Text = urlhash.Value;
}
```

I'm assuming this is a timing issue where the client-side hasn't returned the hash value by the time I reach the OnPreRender event.  Is there a way to get the hash value sooner so I can access it in OnPreRender or sooner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `.ready()` will mean that the JQuery will not execute until the DOM is in a Ready state. This would be at the completion of the page generally. This would also mean that your .NET would have already sent all the HTML to the client by this time. Aside, you may want to tag this for `c#` or `.net` to get their feedback if you want it.

Comment: I do more work in PHP, so I would just get the hash from the URL directly in PHP: `$_GET['hash'];` Could try `Request.QueryString["hash"]` or `Request["hash"]` to get it right away and work with it before presenting to the client.

Comment: There is a syntax issue : <%:urlhash.ClientID%> should be <%=urlhash.ClientID%>. Also, you should have the value intercepted on Page_Load instead of OnPreRender since the values of the controls is not set during OnPreRender. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: @DinoMyte:  I have been getting the hash value correctly with the :urlhash.  However, I did try both of your suggestions (using =urlhash and moving the TextBoxTest.Text = urlhash.Value), but my Textbox is still empty.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @Twisty:  I added the C# tag to this question; thanks for that suggestion.  Unfortunately, Request.QueryString["hash"] and Request["hash"] both return null.

Comment: @techdave3349: Did you try the expression in page_load instead of OnPreRender ?

Comment: @DinoMyte:  Yes.  It did not work unfortunately.